# Can We Close and Open Connection from Bean Configuration?

Tags: spring-boot, hikaricp, spring-mybatis

So, i creating some connection with database using `@bean` configuration and using `hikariCP` for the datasource. This is some code i made.

DatabaseConfiguration.java

```
...
    @Primary
    public SqlSessionFactoryBean logSessionFactory(@Named(ResourceConfiguration.LOG) final DataSource dataSource) throws Exception{
        SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
        sqlSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        SqlSessionFactory sqlSessionFactory;
        sqlSessionFactory = sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject();
        sqlSessionFactory.getConfiguration().addMapper(LogMapper.class);
        return sqlSessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public MapperFactoryBean<LogMapper> logMapperMapperFactoryBean(@Named(LOG) final SqlSessionFactoryBean sqlSessionFactoryBean) throws Exception {
        MapperFactoryBean<LogMapper> factoryBean = new MapperFactoryBean<>(LogMapper.class);
        factoryBean.setSqlSessionFactory(sqlSessionFactoryBean.getObject());
    return factoryBean;
}
...
```

ResourceConfiguration.java

```
...
    @Bean(name = LOG, destroyMethod = "")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.log")
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSourceLog() {
        return new HikariDataSource();
    }
...
```

application-properties

```
...
datasource.log.jdbcUrl=<....>
datasource.log.username=<....>
datasource.log.password=<....>
datasource.log.maximum-pool-size=10
datasource.log.max-lifetime=0
datasource.log.idle-timeout=300000
datasource.log.leak-detection-threshold=2000
datasource.log.connection-timeout=30000
datasource.log.leak-detection-threshold=30000
datasource.log.initialization-fail-timeout=0
...
```

The program always open to get connection for 1st time if the mapper got hit and i'm calling the mapper class using `@Autowired` when i need it. I'm expecting to use open close connection but it's doesn't. When the connection broken, `hikariCP` always giving me `connection timeout 30000ms`. Is there a way to get the SqlSessionFactory to close or open connection when the connection error?

Answer (score 0):

Well, my short answer is that you don't need to bother DB connections when you have Connection Pool such as Hikari. You eventually need some way to query your DB, right? You can do it with a @Repository interface that extends either CrudRepository or JpaRepository. This way you quickly get up and running.
Managing DB Connections manually is not a good idea if you took Spring Boot.

Comment: so we don't need to open and close connection?

Comment: Yes, you're right. The pool itself manages life-cycle of connections. It creates and opens new connections on heavy DB usage; and it closes open connections when DB usage is poor. It also closes them on shutdown.